# PHP cutting off text from a query result

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I created a prepared statement to fetch some results from a MySQL DB, and then I want to display those results in several  boxes on the same page.

I use the same prepared statement a couple of times, to fetch different result sets, and then use a snippet that will turn them into a  menu.

What goes wrong: in some of the select boxes, the text gets cut off randomly. Let's say the text in the DB says "This is a long text", and I get "This is a long t". On another field, it just gives the initial letter "E", instead of the 3 words included.

If I remove `$stmtPedibles->store_result();`, the text will not get cut off anymore. Yet, if I do this, I can't use `<?php if ($executed_stmt->num_rows > 0) :  ?>` in the select box snippet, and this is important to me, since I need to know if the select box is empty. Is there a workaround?

**The code:**

*1. The Main Document*

```
   <?php 
    $root = "";
    $thisfile = "index.php";
    require_once($root."includes/setup/user.php");
    require($root."includes/snippets/prepared_queries.php");
    require_once($root."includes/layout/doc_head.php");
    $thisGerencia = "Produccion"; //Ventas, Almacen, Produccion

    //Variables que se repiten en toda la página
    $ped_gerencia = $thisGerencia;
    $ped_usuario = $thisUsr;
?>
<body>
    <h2>Elementos disponibles</h2>
    <h3><?php echo strtoupper($thisGerencia);?> - Diálogos disponibles: </h3>
    <p>Prep statement + build function</p>

    <?php  //PEDIDO 1
    $ped_tipo = "Q";
    $stmtPedibles->execute(); //4. Execute
    $stmtPedibles->bind_result($selText, $selValue, $nada1, $nada2); //5. Bind results (for selects, always include $selValue and $selCodigo)

    //Vars para select: 
    $executed_stmt = $stmtPedibles; //Esto hace que el siguiente snippet funcione. 
    $select_name = "dialogos_pedibles";
    $select_required = TRUE;
    $select_selected = FALSE;
    $default_option_text = "Hacer una pregunta...";

    include($root."includes/snippets/select_box.php");

    ?>
    <?php  //PEDIDO 2

    $ped_tipo = "I";
    $stmtPedibles->execute(); //4. Execute
    $stmtPedibles->bind_result($selText, $selValue, $nada1, $nada2); //5. Bind results (for selects, always include $selValue and $selCodigo)

    //Vars para select: 
    $executed_stmt = $stmtPedibles; //Esto hace que el siguiente snippet funcione. 
    $select_name = "dialogos_pedibles";
    //$select_required = TRUE;
    $select_selected = FALSE;
    $default_option_text = "Hacer una pregunta...";

    include($root."includes/snippets/select_box.php");

    ?>
    <h3><?php echo strtoupper($thisGerencia);?> - Informes disponibles: </h3>
    <?php //PEDIDO 3
    $ped_tipo = "P";
    $stmtPedibles->execute(); //4. Execute
    $stmtPedibles->bind_result($selText, $selValue, $nada1, $nada2); //5. Bind results (for selects, always include $selValue and $selCodigo)

    //Vars para select: 
    $executed_stmt = $stmtPedibles; //Esto hace que el siguiente snippet funcione. 
    $select_name = "informes_pedibles";
    //$select_required = TRUE;
    $select_selected = FALSE;
    $default_option_text = "Solicitar un informe...";
    include($root."includes/snippets/select_box.php");

    $executed_stmt->close();
    $stmtPedibles->close();
    ?>
<?php include($root."includes/setup/user_footer.php");?>
</body>
</html>
```

*2. The prepared statement*

```
<?php 
$prep_elementos_pedibles = "SELECT EvePar_Pregunta, EvePar_EventoCodigo, EvePar_EventoNombre, EvePar_CodigoInforme
            FROM Estado_Jugador JOIN Eventos_Parametros ON Estado_Codigo = EvePar_EventoCodigo
            WHERE EvePar_EventoLugar = ? AND Estado_Habilitado = 1 AND Evento_EventoTipo = ? AND Estado_usr_name = ?";

$stmtPedibles = $connection->prepare($prep_elementos_pedibles); //1. Prepare
if (!$stmtPedibles) { //2. Check for errors 
    trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $prep_elementos_pedibles . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR); 
}
$stmtPedibles->bind_param("sss", $ped_gerencia, $ped_tipo, $ped_usuario); //3. Bind
?>
```

*3. The select_box snippet*

```
    <?php  
//THIS WAY; TEXT GETS CUT OFF
$executed_stmt->store_result();
if ($executed_stmt->num_rows > 0) :  ?>
    <select name="<?php echo $select_name;?>" class="<?php if ($select_required) {echo "required";} ?>">
        <?php if ($default_option_text !="") : ?>
            <option value=""><?php echo $default_option_text;?></option>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php while ($executed_stmt->fetch()) :
                if ($select_selected == $selValue) {
                    $selected = " selected='selected' "; 
                } else {
                    $selected = "";
                }
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $selValue;?>" <?php echo $selected;?> ><?php echo $selText;?></option>
        <?php endwhile;?>
    </select>
<?php endif;
    $executed_stmt->free_result();
?>
```

**EDIT 1:** 
I just cleaned up the code, as bad_boy mentioned that I should not be creating some variables. I moved `store_result` and `free_result` to the select box snippet, hoping they would make a difference but they don't.

I'm also attaching the screenshots for the table structure:
[image: This is EventoParametros, where the cut off text comes from]
[image: This is Estado_Jugador, used in the JOIN]

Should I give up on using num_rows? That would mean that I give up on prepared statements too really... Is MySQLi any more secure than MySQL statements if I don't use prepared statements? It's really frustrating... :-(

Comment: By the way, you're coding it wrong since the beginning. PHP code should be decoupled from HTML markup as much as possible. You should only use those variables inside a markup, not create them

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but this is mostly code that I tried to isolate from the actual project, to test this bug out. I need the complete text from the DB before I clean this up...

Comment: Well... can you post you MySQL structure (The text that you copy-paste to create a table) ?

Comment: I don't have that SQL structure right now, I'll try to get it. If you're wondering the column types, the one that is used for $selected is TEXT. The entire text shows when I don't use store_result(), so it is properly stored in the DB.

Comment: @bad_boy I just added the table structures to the post. I also think I got what you meant by using the variables, not creating them, I changed the code a bit (it's not MVC yet tho)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know why it is doing the random-text-cutting-off thing, but it seems like you could eliminate the need to check num_rows if you could slightly reorganize how the select box is being built.  I think if you make a string that contains all your `<option>`s, then do your `while ... fetch...` thing to create the list of options, then you can just build the rest of the `<select>` around it if it is not empty, or if it is, don't.  Something like this:

```
<?php
$options = "";
while ($executed_stmt->fetch()) {
    if ($select_selected == $selValue) {
        $selected = " selected='selected' "; 
    } else {
        $selected = "";
    }
    $options .= "<option value=\"$selValue\"$selected>$selText</option>";
}
?>
<?php if ($options) : ?>
    <select name="<?php echo $select_name;?>" class="<?php if ($select_required) {echo "required";} ?>">
        <?php if ($default_option_text !="") : ?>
            <option value=""><?php echo $default_option_text;?></option>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php echo $options;?>
    </select>        
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This seems like a good workaround for a select box, but I'm a bit worried what it would do in other cases. I am going to be working with massive amounts of data on this project, with lots of rows and columns returned in each query. I think num_rows will be important in the rest of the project, and creating intermediate variables for everything I want to do seems complicated. Not to mention that this is the first time I'm using prepared statements, and having to think everything that different from how I used to, might increase development times way too much.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen PHP chop a string to one character before.
PHP treats arrays and strings very similarly.  So if you have what you think is an array and you're trying to say

```
$array = array('key'=>'value');
echo $array['key'];
```

> `value`

but $array actually is a string

```
$array = 'value'
echo $array['key'];
```

> `v`

Because PHP evaluates the 'key' to be "TRUE" and True evaluates to 1 and then it spits out the 1st letter of the string (this may be the index of 1 so the output would be `a` but the point is still the same that it outputs 1 character of the variable.

As for it truncating the string for some of the variables, this is likely a function of inserting in to your table with a varchar of (20) or something shorter than the string length.  Therefore it is being saved as a truncated string and returning what it could.

Comment: Thanks Alan. I thought about the column type, but it is not a VARCHAR, all four of the fetched columns are TEXT columns. I don't see how it could treat my returned string as an array either, as I'm binding it and echoing it, nothing else...